# making urls for django and gitlab CI

Tags: django, dns, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci

I have a droplet in Digitalocean where I installed gitlab CI

The problem is that every domain I create it redirects to gitlab page

How can I make only 1 url that takes to gitlab ci and one for django?